# Does RSpec seeds run the same on different machines?

Tags: rspec

I am trying to set up CI using Travis. But I'm running into tests failing on Travis but not locally, even providing the same seed.

I thought the seeds run the same but now I am unsure and would like to make it clear wether it does or not so I now where to look at.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the errors? Also, check if you have some rows that are in your local database for tests and are not in your seed.

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata Tests failing are random. Guess it depends of the seed. But I am not looking for help resolving my problems, I am just concerned about how seeds work within rspec :)

Comment: @AdrienGiboire are you talking about setting a seed when running your tests and asking if the order is the same (with the same seed) on different machines? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order

Comment: @fabersky To explicit a little bit, a seed is mentioned in the logs of my CI. I run locally the specs setting the same seed. Is the order of specs exactly the same even though it's not the same machine/environment?

Comment: @fabersky, I have the same question: is the order of specs exactly the same with the same seed on different machines?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/7b6b9c3f2e2878213f97d6fc9e9eb23c323cfe1c/features/command_line/randomization.feature) RSpec feature page:

> In Ruby, randomness is seeded by calling `srand` and passing it the seed that
>     you want to use. By doing this, subsequent calls to `rand`, `shuffle`,
>     `sample`, etc. will all be randomized the same way given the same seed is
>     passed to `srand`.

So in short, yes, it will run in the same order on other machines.

Ruby's `srand` does guarantee the same numbers across machines using the same Ruby version. See this SO question and resulting answers: [Does seed generate same random sequence across different Rubys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974284/does-seed-generate-same-random-sequence-across-different-rubys)

Comment: I don't think that clears it up, really. It could just be referring to it being "randomized the same way" on the same machine.

Comment: Fortunately it's not because I've tested and used this with large teams working on CI flows for several years. I'm quite sure that is what they mean.